# Client Id blank in “API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days” Report - when testing from an Android app

Tags: android, salesforce

We have created an Android app which communicates with the Salesforce via Salesforce Mobile SDK and its APIs. As part of the settings we created a connected app in salesforce, obtained a clientId(consumer_key) and consumer_secret. Now we started using the app which can make a maximum of 1000 API calls in a day.

But whil running the "API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days" - Report, the report doesn't show the name of our connected app in the column client id (see picture). What do we need to setup to see our connected app name in that column? Or how can we differentiate that only our Android app made "n" no. of API calls?

[image]